# sp_executesql: Add column with case statement

Tags: sql-server, sp-executesql

This is an example code of what I would like to achieve, I want to add a column to a table with some specific code variables. However, I can't really grasp how the sp_executesql passes it through. Any help appreciated

```
DECLARE @SQLQUERY NVARCHAR (max)
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR (200) = 'Table_Name'
DECLARE @Column VARCHAR (200) = 'Column_Name'

DECLARE @Code1 int = 1
DECLARE @Code2 int = 2
DECLARE @Code3 int = 3

SET @SQLQUERY = 'ALTER TABLE' + @Table + 'ADD' @Column 
AS CASE WHEN FirstColumn IS NULL THEN @Code1
        WHEN SecondColumn IS NULL THEN @Code2
    ELSE @Code3

Exec sp_executesql @SQLQUERY
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Adding a computed column to your table?

Comment: Do you expect `ALTER TABLETable_NameADDColumn_Name` to work without spaces? Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to build the `alter` statement all as string and then execute it, for example your query should be like this:

```
SET @SQLQUERY = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @Table + ' ADD ' + @Column  + 
' AS CASE WHEN FirstColumn IS NULL THEN ' + str(@Code1) + 
       ' WHEN SecondColumn IS NULL THEN ' + str(@Code2) +
   ' ELSE ' + str(@Code3) + ' END'
```

**Note:** I used `str(@Code1)` since it was declared as `int`

then you can execute the statement normally

```
Exec sp_executesql @SQLQUERY
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Hi, now it gave me the error unknown object type 'TABLEtable_nameADDColumn_Name' used in a create, drop or alter statement. Any hint what that might be?

Comment: you should put the correct Table name and also i will edit the answer to add space before the _ADD_

Comment: I updated the answer by adding the proper spacing, but you need to use the correct table_name  which exists

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

You need to build the query as string.

I have noticed few problems on your query:

- FirstColumn and SecondColumn are not declared column
- When you want to add new column, you need to specify the datatype for the column. please see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

  ALTER TABLE Tablecolumn ALTER COLUMN NewColumn NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL;

for the conditions for @Code1, @Code2 and @Code3. You want this as default values? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's going to be a computed column, which are going to get a certain code depending on the condition. The codes are going to be dynamic, so that's going to change later. However, I just want to get the first part to work first.

Answer (score 0):

The script finally worked accordingly to this:

```
DECLARE @Code1 int = 1
DECLARE @Code2 int = 2
DECLARE @Code3 int = 3
DECLARE @SQLQUERY NVARCHAR (max)

SET @SQLQUERY = N'ALTER TABLE Table ADD Column 
AS CASE WHEN FirstColumn IS NULL THEN' STR(@Code1) +
    'WHEN SecondColumn IS NULL THEN' STR(@Code2) +
' ELSE' str(@Code3) + ' END'

Exec sp_executesql @SQLQUERY
```

Comment: The lack of spaces in `THEN'`, `'WHEN` and `ELSE'` will be problematic. The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.